# Pulling objects from json

Tags: json, http, angular, typescript

I have an API that sends an array of objects. Each object contains 2 arrays (1 number and 1 string) and a string. I receive a JSON object from my API successfully and i can display the object to my console from inside my http function and assign it to the var 'chats'. However i am struggling to get data out of the title var object when i want to use it in other parts of this classes code.

For example if i try to assign one of the json childrens arrays eg `someNewVar= this.title[0]` i get a

> string is not accessible to type string

Can anyone tell me for example how i might get the string array called 'labels' out of my object? But when i display this.title[0] to the console it says its a object.

My code

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpWebServiceService1 } from './http-web-service-service';
//Featureupdate: if data point is zero set to null as helps with y-axis range calc. How: create method to concatentate a string[] and run method against charts 2-7
//Feature update: rotate the graphes by populating a new chartDate array and rotating around each position
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  providers: [HttpWebServiceService1]
})
export class AppComponent {
  presscologo = 'logo.png';
    charts:string[];

  constructor(HttpWebServiceService1: HttpWebServiceService1){
    HttpWebServiceService1.getHTTP()
      .subscribe(
        resBody => this.charts = resBody.charts,
        error => console.error('Error: ' + error),
        () => console.log(this.charts[0])

      );
  }
}
```

My JSON

```
{
    "charts": [{
        "title": "title 1",
        "labels": ["label1", "label2", "label3", "label4", "label5", "label6", "label7", "label8", "label9", "label10", "label11", "label12", "label13", "label14", "label15", "label16", "label17", "label18", "label19"],
        "dataObjects": [{
            "values": [3, 1, 1, "NULL", 2, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 4, 2, 2, 0],
            "type": "bar"
        }]
    }, {
        "title": "title 2",
        "labels": ["label1", "label2", "label3", "label4", "label5", "label6", "label7", "label8", "label9", "label10", "label11", "label12", "label13", "label14", "label15", "label16", "label17", "label18", "label19"],
        "dataObjects": [{
            "values": [3, 1, 1, "NULL", 2, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 4, 2, 2, 0],
            "type": "bar"
        }]
    }]
}
```

Comment: Can you add the value of `this.title` to your question?

Comment: hey, thx for answering....yes i added it there.. note i changes the var from'title' to 'charts' as its clearer that way

Comment: So `this.charts[0].labels` doesn't work?

Comment: If i create a var e.g. test:string[] = this.charts[0].labels elsewhere in code it complains this.charts[0].labels does not exist...which it doesnt of course.

Comment: Are you trying to create this `var` outside of the `subscribe`?

Comment: yes...i want to do stuff outside of the subscribe with my json....

Comment: Do you know how asynchronous functions work?

Comment: so thats the bit thats confusing me...can i re-enter my code when the subscribe completes?

Comment: If you are waiting for a result from an async operation in order to do stuff with it; you need to do it when the result arrives right? When the result arrives, it will be inside the callback which is your subscribe function. So you must do whatever you want to do inside the subscribe. Rest of your code(sync) will be executed before the result arrives.

Comment: Thx echonax, appreciate that.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot comment yet so I will write this as an answer and hope it helps.

You need to bind the data you get from the server and the data model that you are using in your application.

Try creating this data model (**chart.model.ts**)

```
class DataObject{
   values: number[];
   type: string;
}

export class Chart {
  title: string;
  labels: string[];
  dataObjects: DataObject[]
}
```

make sure you are getting a response from your server as array of Charts (`Chart[]`), and the `getHTTP()` in your http service should return an `Observable<Chart[]>`.

now you declare your charts as Chart[] (`charts: Chart[]`)

**edit based on request**:

Charts Service (**charts/charts.service.ts**):

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Chart } from './charts/chart.model'
import { Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';

// Import RxJs required methods
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';

@Injectable()
export class ChartsService {
   // resolve HTTP using the constructor
   constructor (private http: Http) {}
   // example of url of charts
   private chartsUrl = 'http://localhost:9000/api/charts'; 

   // fetch all existing charts
   getCharts() : Observable<Chart[]> {
     // ...using get request
     return this.http.get(this.chartsUrl).map((res:Response) => res.json()).catch((error:any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error'));
   }
}
```

App Component:

```
import { Component , OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { Chart } from './charts/chart.model'
import { ChartsService } from './charts/charts.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  providers: [ChartsService]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  presscologo = 'logo.png';
  charts:Chart[];

  constructor(private chartsService: ChartsService){}
  ngOnInit() {
     this.chartsService.getCharts()
        .subscribe(
            charts => {
                this.charts = charts; 
                console.log(this.charts);
            },
            error => console.error('Error: ' + error)
        );
  }
}
```

this should work!

Comment: thx Omarllias... I have a few questions though. How do i make sure i am getting a response from server as array of Charts? Is it not already an array of charts? and second...can you show me how to return Observable<Chart[]> from http?

Comment: define a function named `getCharts()` inside your service, i will call it, `chartsService`, instead of, `HttpWebServiceService1`. The signature of this method should be `getCharts():Observable<Chart[]>`. What this function does: it returns `return this.http.get(this.chartsUrl).map((res:Response) => res.json()).catch((error:any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error'));`

Comment: ok, you will have to put that in the answer for me as i'm still not clear. I may need to do a bit of research. Can you take my code and edit so i can follow? I am not 100% sure how to change the values in the rest of my code once the async comes back

Comment: sure! put it in a plunker and share the link

Answer (score 0):

If you just assign your json like so from your http call:

Service:

```
getHTTP() {
  return this.http.get('url')
    .map(res => res.json())
}
```

you will end up with an Object, since that what's returned is an object. If you want to extract the array of objects, extract it from the object `charts`:

```
getHTTP() {
  return this.http.get('url')
    .map(res => res.json().charts)
}
```

Then you have an array of objects, which you can easily access.

As per comments, you need to do the data manipulation inside `subscribe` since this is an async operation, doing it outside, you most likely would end up with your app throwing an error because there are no values present. So something like this:

```
HttpWebServiceService1.getHTTP()
  .subscribe(data => {
     this.charts = data;
     // here do your manipulation!
     console.log(this.charts[0].title)
  });
```

Hope this helps! :)